# How to add custom field to auth_permission model in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-permissions

I am working with auth_permission model and to add extra fields in this model.

```
class Permission(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_('content type'),
    )
    codename = models.CharField(_('codename'), max_length=100)
```

Extra field I wanted to add is

```
application_id = models.ForeignKey(ApplicationTbl, db_column='application_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=False)
```

Can someone tell the work around to add it to **auth_permission** model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your `models.py` put this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

# inject application_id atribute to the Django Permission model
if not hasattr(Permission, 'application_id'):
    application_id = models.ForeignKey(ApplicationTbl, db_column='application_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=False)
    application_id.contribute_to_class(Permission, 'application_id')
```

After that, run migration and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

The [official standard way in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) to do this is to define it in class Meta inside your model; which if it's your user model, you could also consider customizing it by using [PermissionsMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin);
which I believe is also applicable in your case if you put everything in its right place.
You have not provided much detail about your system and what you're trying to do but I guess you're trying to figure out in which application context the user is doing his activity. In that case and if your system is of a reasonably big scale, you could also try considering user authentication backend as a separate app folder in your Django project. hope I could help.